# dynamic collection of text from text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is html code

```
<div id="domTxtEntry">
    <strong>Your Name:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="txtdisplay" id="txtdisplay" value="" class="input" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="domPrv"></div>
</div>
```

this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nameNode = $('#domPrv'),
        name = $('#txtdisplay');
    //comment...easy
    $('#domTxtEntry input').bind('blur keyup', function () {
        //name
        if ($('#txtdisplay').val()) {
            nameNode.text(name.val() + ' modifies this');
        }
    });
});
```

this is here in this fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qSq37/1/

two problems

1. on deletion of values from textfield the output windows does not update it or leaves at the last word.
2. i tried many things to add the output to float on the right of the text field but it is displayed at the bottom of the text field.

Help needed.

Comment: For the second problem, search the site for `divs on same line`, you'll find many answers.

Comment: @Barmar can it happen that this shows some default value in the starting? it just appears from nothing ;(

Comment: Put something in the original HTML.

Comment: Fixes for both problems http://jsfiddle.net/qSq37/2/

Comment: @Barmar i put something in org html but that stays there even if it is updated..

Comment: If you put it inside the `domPrv` div, it should be replaced by your jQuery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that when the input is empty, calling `.val()` returns false, so the value in `#txtdisplay` is not updated. Try this:

```
$('#domTxtEntry input').bind('blur keyup', function () {
  if ($('#txtdisplay').val()) {
    nameNode.text(name.val() + ' modifies this');
  } else {
    nameNode.text("Default value");
  }
});
```

The second problem you can solve like this (removed the `<br />` tags):

```
<div id="domTxtEntry">
    <strong>Your Name:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="txtdisplay" id="txtdisplay" value="" class="input" />

    <div id="domPrv">Default value</div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#domPrv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can it happen that this shows some default value in the starting? it just appears from nothing ;(

Comment: If you want a default value you can start your `domPrv` with a value and in the `else` condition put the same value. :)

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your needs, also updated the CSS part.

Comment: sorry to bother you again.. can i add a check for not addition of space or special characters and it shall add warning to user? please update this.. http://jsfiddle.net/qSq37/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25421/discussion-between-kaeros-and-user2057047)